# Selection and filter not working with d3.js pie chart

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to make a selection of the arcs in a pie layout in d3.js and my selections are not working. What I want to do is select based on a random string 'bafg' and if one letter matches the data selection, I want that arc to be highlighted and then get the transition animation working for that selected arc. I've tried different selections and they don't work. Here is some code that shows in the console that the conditions are being filtered but how do I make the selections pick the arc? Only the first arc ever gets selected. Thanks for any help! https://jsfiddle.net/wheatgrass/abyubk4a/3/

```
   `     <html>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <title>pie test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/camp/simon/s8.css">
        <script src="/jquery/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="/d3new/d3.js"></script>
        <head>
        <style>
        #container {
            position:absolute;
            top:0px;
            left:30%;
            width:600px;
            height: 600px; 
         border-style:solid;
         border-width:2px;
         border-color:blue;
        }

        #pieChart {    
            position:relative;
            top:20px;
            left:20%;
            width:400px;
            height: 400px; 
         border-style:solid;
         border-width:2px;
         border-color:red;
        }

        .onButton {
        position:relative;
            top:10px;
            left:30%;
         width: 20px;
         height: 20px;
         border-style:solid;
         border-width:2px;
         border-color:green;
        }
        #green {
        color: green;
        }

        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <script>

        window.onload = function() {

        var testString = 'bafg';
        /*
        ############# PIE CHART ###################
        -------------------------------------------
        */
        function getRandomItem(){ //returns one letter in string
        var aString;
            list = ["a","b","f","g"];
           var randomItems = function(list) {
            return list[Math.floor((Math.random()*list.length))];
             }
             aString = randomItems(list);
             console.log("returning aString ", aString );
             return aString;
        } //end getRandomItem


        function pieChart(){

            var dataset = [
                  {color: "blue", id:1, class:"blue", item: "b", amount: 25 },
                  {color: "yellow", id:2, class:"yellow", item: "a", amount: 25},
                  {color: "green", id:3,class:"green", item: "f", amount: 25},
                  {color: "red", id: 4,class:"red", item: "g", amount: 25}
                  ]
                  ;

            var width = 400,
           height = 400,
           outerRadius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
           innerRadius = outerRadius * .999,   
           // for animation
           innerRadiusFinal = outerRadius * .5,
           innerRadiusFinal3 = outerRadius* .45
           ;

            var vis = d3.select("#pieChart")
         .append("svg:svg")      //create the SVG element inside the <body>
         .data([dataset])      //associate our data with the document
         .attr("width", width)           //set the width and height of our visualization (these will be attributes of the <svg> tag
         .attr("height", height)
         .append("svg:g")                //make a group to hold our pie chart
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + outerRadius + "," + outerRadius + ")")    //move the center of the pie chart from 0, 0 to radius, radius
                ;

           var arc = d3.svg.arc()              //this will create <path> elements for us using arc data
            .outerRadius(outerRadius).innerRadius(innerRadius);

           // for animation
           var arcFinal =                 d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(innerRadiusFinal).outerRadius(outerRadius);
            var arcFinal3 = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(innerRadiusFinal3).outerRadius(outerRadius);

           var pie = d3.layout.pie()           //this will create arc data for us given a list of values
                .value(function(d) { return d.amount; });    //access the value of each element in our data array
           var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")     //this selects all <g> elements with class slice (there aren't any yet)
                .data(pie)                          //associate the generated pie data (an array of arcs, each having startAngle, endAngle and value properties) 
                .enter()                            //this will create <g> elements for every "extra" data element that should be associated with a selection. The result is creating a <g> for every object in the data array
                    .append("svg:g")                //create a group to hold each slice (we will have a <path> and a <text> element associated with each slice)
               .attr("class", "slice")    //allow us to style things in the slices (like text)
                    ;

                arcs.append("svg:path")
                    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { 
                  return d.data.color; } ) //set the color for each slice to be chosen from the color function defined above
                       .attr("d", arc)     //this creates the actual SVG path using the associated data (pie) with the arc drawing function
                        .attr("d", function(d,i) {
                            console.log("what in d,i",d,i);} )
;
                     d3.select("#onButton") 
                       .on("click", function() {`enter code here`
                 var getItem = getRandomItem();
                 console.log('getItem', getItem);
                 console.log("clicked on button ");
                        arcs.filter(function (d) { 
                        console.log("find pathnumber in d",d);
})
                .attr('fill', 'black');
;
                            arcs.transition()
                .duration(750)
                .delay(10)
                .attr("d", arcFinal )
                             .attr("startAngle", function(d, i) { 
                                 console.log("d", d);
                                if ( (d.startAngle === 0) &&
                                 (getItem === d.data.item)) {
                                 console.log("d.item", d.data.item);
                                  console.log("item",getItem.charAt(0)); 
                                 console.log("d.id",d.data.id);
                                 return d.startAngle;
                                 } 
                                if ( (d.startAngle === 1.5707963267948968) &&
                                 (getItem === d.data.item)) {
                                 console.log("b showing");
                                  console.log( d.data.item.charAt(0)); 
                                 console.log("d.id",d.data.id)
                                 return d.startAngle;
                                 } 
                                if ( (d.startAngle === 3.1415926535897936) &&
                                 (getItem === d.data.item)) {
                                 console.log(" f showing");
                                  console.log( d.data.item.charAt(0)); 
                                 console.log("d.id",d.data.id);
                                 return d.startAngle;
                                 } 
                                if ( (d.startAngle === 4.712388980384691)  &&
                                 (getItem === d.data.item)) {
                                 console.log("g showing ");
                                  console.log( d.data.item.charAt(0)); 
                                 console.log("after filter, d",d);
                                 console.log("d.id",d.data.id);
                                 return d.startAngle;
                                 } 
                                  }) //end attr fill
                                .attr("d", arcFinal3)
                    .attr("stroke","orange")
                    .attr("stroke-width", 10)
                ;


                d3.selectAll("g.slice").selectAll("path").transition()
                .filter(function (d) { return d.startAngle; }) 
                    .attr("stroke","yellow")
                    .attr("stroke-width", 10)
                    .attr("d", arcFinal3)
                                .attr("fill", function (d,i) {
                                 console.log("in transition d,i",d,i);
                     return d.data.color; })
                                 ;
              d3.select("path") 
                .filter(function (d) { return d.startAngle; }) 
                    .attr("stroke","yellow")
                    .attr("stroke-width", 0)
                    .attr("d", arcFinal)
                    ;
            });

        } 
        pieChart();

        }; //end window onload
        </script>
        </body>
        <div id="container"  class="container-class" >

        <div id="onButton" button type="button" placeholder="On"         class="onButton" value="On" >
         </div> <!--onbutton -->
            <div id="pieChart">
           </div>
        </div> <!--container -->
            <script type="text/javascript">
        <div>
        </html>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I have been researching selections since posting this and found how to do what I needed. I had to selectAll, then select, then filter on what condition, then use "each" function to access individual arcs. Here is what I found worked.  Thanks for anyone who tried to help. I am posting for anyone who needs this kind of solution.

```
    <html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>pie test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/camp/simon/s8.css">
<script src="/jquery/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/d3new/d3.js"></script>
<head>
<style>
#container {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:30%;
    width:600px;
    height: 600px; 
 border-style:solid;
 border-width:2px;
 border-color:blue;
}

#pieChart {    
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
    left:20%;
    width:400px;
    height: 400px; 
 border-style:solid;
 border-width:2px;
 border-color:red;
}

.onButton {
position:relative;
    top:10px;
    left:30%;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 border-style:solid;
 border-width:2px;
 border-color:green;
}
</html>
```